# Two Foreign Keys in Asp.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am trying to create a sign up form that uses 3 tables (see below). Each Person gets assigned to one company (1-to-1) and each company has multiple locations (1-m). As far as I understand my table structure is working, but for some reason I cannot get the Location to behave the way it should. When I have 2 Companies and only 1 Location assiged to Company 1, the form allows me to save the data despite no Locations being assigned to company 2. Any ideas?

As seen on picture below both of the fields have dropdowns, but I was hoping the Location dropdown would be dependant on the Company dropdown, yet no matter which combination is chosen the choices get saved.

[image]

Person Table:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //Foreign Key
    [Display(Name = "Company")]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Location")]
    public int? LocationId { get; set; }
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }

}
```

Location Table:

```
public class Location
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

Company Table:

```
public class Company
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}
```

Should I be removing the foreign key relationship between Person and Location and instead doing something else?

Controller Actions:

**GET**

```
    // GET: People/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.CompanyId = new SelectList(db.Companies, "CompanyId", "CompanyName");
        ViewBag.LocationId = new SelectList(db.Locations, "LocationId", "LocationName");
        return View();
    }
```

**POST**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "PersonId,PersonName, CompanyId,LocationId")] Person person)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.People.Add(person);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.CompanyId = new SelectList(db.Companies, "CompanyId", "CompanyName", person.CompanyId);
        ViewBag.LocationId = new SelectList(db.Locations, "LocationId", "LocationName", person.LocationId);
        return View(person);
    }
```

UPDATE #1:

database values:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by the form allows me to save the data? Are you using validation that is not working correctly?

Comment: I think so, I've added my controller code in case the issue lies there.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to create a model for that page instead of using viewbag? That will make it easier to use ModelState.IsValid as you can use the required attribute on your model and if it is valid, do your CRUD code

Comment: @f78xd23 - We really can't understand what exactly is wrong...ie...what you are trying to fix.   You will need to clarify a bit more so we can help.  With that said, I think your models are flawed as they exist in this post.  Currently, your Person class has links to company and location, but that doesn't really make sense given a company can have many locations and a person is tied to only the company.  Ask this question:  Which of the companies' many locations would you expect to be tied to the person?

Comment: @user1011627  Well I want a person to be assigned to one of the locations of one company. I was hoping my code would accomplish that, but its clearly wrong.

Comment: I had a feeling this is what you wanted to accomplish (ie...a default location).  It is possible to do it, but you will have to factor that complexity into your solution.  One of your first obstacles by doing it would be ensuring the location that is assigned to the person is truly a location that is valid for that company.   That aside, it still doesn't answer your original question which personally I still don't understand what your outcome is.  Are you saying you are allowed to save a person without a location?  Is that the issue you are trying to fix?

Comment: Have you made sure in debugging in Post that `person.LocationId` has value? The issue might be binding.

Comment: @user1011627 No. First I create Company A, then assign Location A + B to it, then when creating Person all i want to be able to do is just assign to let's say Location B of Company A. My current problem is that even if I have Company B the location dropdown has all locations and allows me to save any Location ID. Neither Company nor Location should be left blank.

Comment: @Wubbler I've added relevant database data screenshot for person as an update. Weirdly enough there seems to be Company_CompanyId column in there.

Comment: You location list is going to have to be filtered when the user changes the selection of the company.  This is exactly the situation that I was describing above that you will have to code for.  The first thing you would need to do would be have the UI filter off "invalid" locations by company.   The second thing you would need to do is enforce that rule in your business logic because you don't want to rely on the UI to be the enforcer of your data.

Comment: @user1011627 Ok, does that mean I will have to use Ajax to repopulate the Location dropdown? Is there any way to simplify or fix my model relationships to avoid having to write that extra logic? I am asking as you've mentioned my current model structure is wrong.

Comment: @f78xd23 - An ajax call would definitely be 1 way to accomplish it.  Your model isn't "wrong" per se given what you want to accomplish, but it does create a good deal of complexity.  The one big drawback you have with this schema is that your database can't enforce the rule for you...it can enforce that a valid location is tied to the person, but it can't guarantee that the location is also tied to the company that the person belongs to.  That is only a rule you can enforce in your code.

Comment: Do a search for cascading dropdown list...it will give you a ton of example of how to tie 2 dropdowns together.....here is a good example to give you some direction (fyi...this uses razor syntax):
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/creating-simple-cascading-dropdownlist-in-mvc-4-using-razor/

Comment: user1011627 Oh! I've never heard of cascading dropdown lists, sounds like something I need to use. Before we finish, would you create this model differently from me? If so, could you please show me an example as the answer?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see this last message until now.  Since you want to have a person with a default/primary location, this model isn't inherently "wrong", it just has the drawback of not being able to be fully enforced by your database.  In order to redesign your schema, it would require me to know more about your domain.  Questions like, "Why are locations tied to companies?", "Can a company have a primary/default location instead of the person"?, etc.

Comment: If a company can have the primary location, it makes your schema easier to enforce and makes logical sense, but in that case all persons in that company would by definition belong to that default location?  This is not a requirement that I can infer though as I don't know your domain.

Comment: I did manage to get the cascading dropdowns to work, so thanks for that. As to your comment, the only reason my schema is set up like that is because thats the only way it makes sense to me, but at the same time I have concerns about location being a foreign key in two tables that are also linked to eachother. On top of that I will be adding another table called Manager to my schema, which will be assiged to multiple locations, so in a way location is MORE important than the company itself.

Comment: Cool...sounds like your original question has been resolved then.  I know what you mean...I think your schema is fine given your requirement and it makes sense to me as well just has some caveats you have to be aware of.  I would definitely think through the manager piece though...if a manager can belong to multiple locations, I wouldn't be surprised that a "person" could also be assigned multiples in the long-run.  You may want to consider building that in now if you think there is even a chance of it happening...it will be very invasive to change later.